# Estimates for Poisson's equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am studying Calderón-Zygmund estimates ($L^p$ estimates) for Poisson equation. What I already know is:

*Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain, $f \in L^p(\Omega)$, $1<p<\infty$, and let $w$ be the Newtonial Potential of $f$. Then $w \in W^{2,p}(\Omega)$, $\Delta w = f$ a.e. and 
$$
||D^{2}w||_{p} \leq C(n,p) ||f||_{p}
$$
and
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} |D^2w|^2 = \int_{\Omega} f^2.
$$*

Moreover, I know that

*Let $\Omega$ a domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $u \in W^{2,p}_{0}(\Omega)$, $1<p<\infty$. Then
$$
||D^2u||_p \leq C(n,p) ||\Delta u||_p
$$
and if $p=2$,
$$
||D^2 u||^2_2 = ||\Delta u||^{2}_{2}.
$$*

My question is how to extend the first theorem to solutions of the Poisson equation in $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$, i.e., given $u \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$, if $\Delta u \in L^{p}$, then $u \in W^{2,p}(\Omega)$?

I'm following the book by Gilbarg and Trudinger "Elliptic Partial DIfferential Equations of Second Order" but I cannot find there what I really want to.